# Trouble with Swift 3 - MSStickerBrowserView and scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, message, swift3

Alright, I'm having some issues in `Swift 3` while trying desperately to add an `MSStickerBrowserView` to a `UIScrollview`.

I'm working in a message extension app and have added my `scrollview` via storyboard (I usually make them programmatically but I thought it'd be easier with constraints). I have connected the `scrollview` as an outlet in my `MessagesViewController` script.

I need to add an `MSStickerBrowser` I have created as a `subview` of this `scrollview`, meaning the user would be able to scroll TO the browser view and then scroll through the actual browser.

This is how I create my browser view normally and add it to the view - when added to the view it all works as it should:

```
func createStickerBrowser() {
        let controller = MSStickerBrowserViewController(stickerSize: .large)


        addChildViewController(controller)
       view.addSubview(controller.view)

        controller.stickerBrowserView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        controller.stickerBrowserView.dataSource = self

        //resize this programmatically later
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

I don't know a lot about MSStickerBrowsers because the tutorials have been limited, however I know this ties the browser's size to that of the changing Message VC and adds it as a normal subview.

I then tried logically to just add it as a subview of the scrollview instead:

```
let controller = MSStickerBrowserViewController(stickerSize: .large)
        //controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height * 0.5)

        addChildViewController(controller)
       scrollView.addSubview(controller.view)

        controller.stickerBrowserView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        controller.stickerBrowserView.dataSource = self

        //resize this programmatically later
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
```

I've tried several variations but no matter what the sticker browser view is nowhere. The `scrollview` is there, not the browser, and no errors on that are printed to the console.

This seems like it should be simple - what am I doing wrong?